# how to get location continuously using GPS and AGPS in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have written the following code to find the location in blackberry but sometimes I am getting invalid location instance. What value should be passed to location listener to get location continuously?

```
package com.sims.sendlocation;

                /**
                 * 
                 * @author PramodKumarVishwakarma
                 *
                 */
                import java.util.Calendar;
                import java.util.TimerTask;

                import javax.microedition.location.Criteria;
                import javax.microedition.location.Location;
                import javax.microedition.location.LocationListener;
                import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;

                import com.sims.commonmethods.Constants;
                import com.sims.datahandler.GPRSHandler;
                import com.sims.rms.RMSHandler;

                public class LocationTimerTask extends TimerTask implements LocationListener {

                    private String locationStr;
                    private LocationProvider provider;
                    private String exception;

                    public void run() 
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();         
                            criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
                            //criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);       
                        provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);      
                        provider.setLocationListener(this, -1, -1, -1);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        RMSHandler.addDataValues(Constants.CURRENT_LOCATION,"Provider Initialization: " + e.getMessage());
                        System.out.println("***********"+e);
                    }

                    if (checkTimeToSendMail())
                        startRequestThread();
                }

                public boolean cancel() {
                    return false;

                }

                private void startRequestThread()
                {
                    final GPRSHandler gprs = new GPRSHandler();


                    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                sleep(Constants.MINUTE * Constants.LOC_THREAD_WAIT);
                                {
                                    FindLocationReceiver location = new FindLocationReceiver();

                                    location.sendOrderToServer(RMSHandler.getDataValues(Constants.IP_INFO)+ gprs.updateConnectionSuffix().trim());
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                            {
                                //Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK, "startRequestThread:   " + e);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        thread.start();
                    }

                    private boolean checkTimeToSendMail() {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);

                        if (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) {
                            if (hour >= Constants.MNG_TIME)
                                return true;
                        } else {
                            if (hour < Constants.EVNG_TIME)
                                return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }

                    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location)
                {
                        if (location.isValid()) 
                        {
                            locationStr = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()+ "-" + location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();

                        RMSHandler.addDataValues(Constants.CURRENT_LOCATION, locationStr);

                    } 
                    else

                        RMSHandler.addDataValues(Constants.CURRENT_LOCATION,"Not valid Location Provider");
                    }

                    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) 
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Sometimes I am able to get a valid location but other times I am not able to get a valid location. What value should be passed in Listener parameter list?

Comment: check this http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/latitude-and-longitude-in-bb.html

Comment: no my requirement is how to get continuously  location ...

Comment: Now I'm confused. Is your problem getting locations continuously or that you are getting invalid locations? It is normal to occasionally get invalid locations depending on the quality of the GPS signal.

Comment: ya sometime we r getting  invalid locations depending on the quality of the GPS signal ..how we can resolve that with our code...so we will able to location continuously or how we can refresh the strength of signal